# Javascript refactoring help needed

Tags: javascript, refactoring, toggle

I have an image toggle triggered by button clicks and checkboxes. My code is currently working how I need it to, but I'm very new to JavaScript so I'm sure there is a cleaner way to do this.

A few notes:

This is for a client, so for confidentiality reasons, I cannot share the actual images, but the alt tags should tell the story.

I'm not allowed to use anything other than vanilla JS on the platform this will live, and all variables and functions have to have custom names, hence the funky naming.

```js
var csDMU_checkbox = document.getElementById("csDMU_checkbox");
var csDMU_imageBefore = document.getElementById("before-image");
var csDMU_imageAfter = document.getElementById("after-image");
var csDMU_imageCombo = document.getElementById("combo-image");
var csDMU_switch = document.getElementById("switch");
var csDMU_toggle = document.getElementById("toggle");

function csDMU_toggleImage() {
  if (csDMU_checkbox.checked == true) {
    csDMU_imageBefore.style.display = "none";
    csDMU_imageAfter.style.display = "block";
    csDMU_imageCombo.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    csDMU_imageBefore.style.display = "block";
    csDMU_imageAfter.style.display = "none";
    csDMU_imageCombo.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function csDMU_comboView() {
  csDMU_imageCombo.style.display = "block";
  csDMU_imageBefore.style.display = "none";
  csDMU_imageAfter.style.display = "none";
  csDMU_switch.style.display = "none";
  csDMU_toggle.style.display = "block";
}

function csDMU_toggleView() {
  csDMU_switch.style.display = "block";
  csDMU_toggle.style.display = "none";
  csDMU_imageBefore.style.display = "block";
  csDMU_imageCombo.style.display = "none";
}
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Libre+Franklin:ital,wght@0,400;0,700;1,400;1,700&display=swap');

body {
 font-family: 'Libre Franklin', sans-serif;
}
.flexRow {
    display: -webkit-box;
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: flex;
    -webkit-box-align: center;
        -ms-flex-align: center;
            align-items: center;
}

/* The switch - the box around the slider */
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 119px;
  height: 40px;
}

/* Hide default HTML checkbox */
.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

/* The slider */
.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #243b43;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 32px;
  width: 33px;
  right: 4px;
  bottom: 3px;
  background: transparent -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FFFFFF), color-stop(47%, #EDEDED), color-stop(73%, #D0D0D0), to(#E5E5E5)) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  background: transparent linear-gradient(180deg, #FFFFFF 0%, #EDEDED 47%, #D0D0D0 73%, #E5E5E5 100%) 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px #00000029;
  box-shadow: 0px 3px 6px #00000029;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}
.slider:after {
    content: "BEFORE";
    display: block;
    font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 14px;
    letter-spacing: 0.16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: #FFF;
    position: relative;
    top: 13px;
    left: 10px;
}

input:checked + .slider {
  background-color: #F26322;
}

input:focus + .slider {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
}

input:checked + .slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-75px);
  transform: translateX(-75px);
}
input:checked + .slider:after {  
    content:'AFTER';
    left: 50px;
}
/* Rounded sliders */
.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
.combo-button,
.toggle-button{
    width: 172px;
    height: 40px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border-radius: 100px;
    border: 1px solid #C4C4C4;
    color: #4a4b4d;
    letter-spacing: 0.16px;
}
.combo-button:hover,
.combo-button:focus {
    background-color: #002D5E;
    color: #FFF;
}
.combo-button:focus {
    outline: 0;
}
.toggle-button {
    display: none;
    width: 119px;
    margin: 0;
}
.hand-img {
    max-width: 700px;
    margin-right: -20px;
    display: block;
}
#after-image,
#combo-image {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<div id="image-change">
  <img src="" alt="before image" class="hand-img" id="before-image" />
  <img src="" alt="after image" class="hand-img" id="after-image" />
  <img src="" alt="combo image" class="hand-img" id="combo-image" />
</div>
<div class="flexRow">
  <label class="switch" id="switch">
    <input type="checkbox" id="csDMU_checkbox" onclick="csDMU_toggleImage()">
    <span class="slider round"></span>
  </label>
  <button class="toggle-button" id="toggle" onclick="csDMU_toggleView()">TOGGLE VIEW</button>
  <button class="combo-button" onclick="csDMU_comboView()">COMPARISON</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Maybe that's a case for https://codereview.stackexchange.com but not for SO

Comment: If you can tell us more about what the code is supposed to do, yes, this could work on CR. Make sure you read their [FAQ on asking questions](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2436/52915) first!

Comment: I didn't know that was a thing, thank you! I will put it there!

Answer (score 0):

Well you could minimize your JS code by first selecting all the elements using one line selector, note that you need to write the selected elements in their order in HTML to get them right because we're destructuring the returned node list into variables so the order matters because it's an array and not an object, then you are writing repeatedly `element.style.display = "some value"` so you can write a function to do that using an array of elements as input and their display value to set as two arrays and just loop over the first array of the elements and assign the correct CSS display value according to the index, and use a ternary expression instead of If-Else statement too write less code, here is the full JS code

```js
let [csDMU_imageBefore, csDMU_imageAfter, csDMU_imageCombo, csDMU_switch, csDMU_checkbox, csDMU_toggle] = document.querySelectorAll("#before-image, #after-image, #combo-image, #switch, #csDMU_checkbox, #toggle");

const setCssDisplay = (elements, values) => elements.forEach((element, index) => element.style.display = values[index]);

function csDMU_toggleImage() {
  setCssDisplay([csDMU_imageBefore, csDMU_imageAfter, csDMU_imageCombo], csDMU_checkbox.checked ? ["none", "block", "none"] : ["block", "none", "none"]);
}

function csDMU_comboView() {
  setCssDisplay([csDMU_imageCombo, csDMU_imageBefore, csDMU_imageAfter, csDMU_switch, csDMU_toggle], ["block", "none", "none", "none", "block"]);
}

function csDMU_toggleView() {
  setCssDisplay([csDMU_switch, csDMU_toggle, csDMU_imageBefore, csDMU_imageCombo], ["block", "none", "block", "none"]);
}
```